# Libgdx text on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, label, bitmap-fonts

I'm new to libgdx and i'm trying to display some text on the screen.

I've watched several tutorials, and they're all saying that I should initiate the `BitmapFont` with no parameters and it will then use the default font. But on my android device it just shows these black rectangles:
[image: Black rectangles in shape of the letters]

And here's my code:

```
public class GameOverScreen implements Screen {
    private JumpGame game;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;

    private BitmapFont gameOverFont;
    private Label.LabelStyle labelStyle;
    private Label label;

public GameOverScreen(JumpGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();

    gameOverFont = new BitmapFont();
    labelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle(gameOverFont, Color.BLACK);
    label = new Label("Game Over", labelStyle);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    cam.setToOrtho(false, game.getWidth() / 4, game.getHeight() / 4);
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.batch.begin();
    label.draw(game.batch, 1);
    game.batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

**EDIT:**

Okay so I was launching the Screen with the text from a second thread. When I launch it "normally" it works fine. Can someone explain why this is, and how to work around it if I want to still launch it from the thread?

Comment: Is it working fine on desktop ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes, it works on desktop

Comment: All UI things must run on main thread. If you are in another thread, use Gdx.app.postRunnable()

Comment: @RóbertGers what is the value of `game.getWidth()` and `game.getHeight()`

Comment: Yes, thanks @Nathan this helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading)

> To pass data to the rendering thread from another thread we recommend
>   using Application.postRunnable(). This will run the code in the
>   Runnable in the rendering thread in the next frame, before
>   ApplicationListener.render() is called.

---

Label is part of libgdx's 2D scene graph so it's better to use with Stage.

If you want to draw font you can simply draw with the help of `Batch`.

```
font.draw(batch,"Hello World",100,100);
```